# Simulate directory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When my main website opens, it retrieves content from `/home/parsa/public_html`.

I have tried this: `rewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "/ppyazi.com/$1"`

I need it to retrieve the files from `/home/parsa/public_html/ppyazi.com` without redirecting to it on the user side.

Here are some examples:

`index.php` to display contents of `ppyazi.com/index.php`

`users/index.php` to display contents of `ppyazi.com/users/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried this: `rewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "/ppyazi.com/$1"`

In `.htaccess` the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. So, the pattern `^/(.*)$` will never match and your directive does nothing.

However, unless there is also a `.htaccess` file in the `/ppyazi.com` subdirectory with mod_rewrite directives then you need to be careful of rewrite loops.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

rewriteRule !^ppyazi\.com\ /ppyazi.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply checks that the URL does not already start with the directory we are rewriting to. Instead of the `$1` backreference (since we are not capturing anything in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*) we use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. Note that `REQUEST_URI` contains the full URL-path, including the slash prefix, so the slash should be omitted from the *susbstitution* string.

The `L` (`last`) flag is required to prevent any further directives being processed that occur later in the file (in the current round of processing). If this is the last mod_rewrite directive in the file then it is superfluous. Note, however, that in `.htaccess` the rewriting process essentially *starts over* (until the URL passes through unchanged), so other directives might still process the request.

Comment: When I use this, it redirects the user to /ppyazi.com. I want it to redirect, but not let the user see that it is redirected, basically simulate the directory.

Comment: This directive by itself will not _externally redirect_ the request. If you are seeing an _external redirect_ then something else must be triggering that. Have you cleared your browser cache? (If you've previously experimented with 301 redirects then these will have been cached by the browser.) Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: There is nothing related to 301 redirects in my htaccess. Also, what does [L] do?

Comment: The `L` (or `last`) flag stops the current round of processing, preventing any (mod_rewrite) directives that follow being processed. Although it doesn't stop all processing. I've updated my answer. Since you've "accepted" my answer, I assume it is no longer "redirecting"? What was the problem?